# A frame adding a .ttf font into a mixin for text

Tags: aframe

I'm trying to use the Georgia font in A-frame. I found and downloaded it and then uploaded it into assets. It's a .ttf file type, so I'm not sure if that's why it isn't working, but when I try and use it in my code, it doesn't work.

this is the code I tried within asset tags:

a-asset-item id="georgia.ttf" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/b4adbd04-68ad-4b83-8ff1-0cfe5e5c37ec%2Fgeorgia.ttf?v=1619266271805">

a-mixin id="texts" text="color: #303030; width: 1.8; lineHeight: 60; align: center; baseline: top; wrapCount: 12; font: georgia.ttf">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using fonts in 3D is not that simple. Every single character must be rerendered using geometry or textures. I strongly recommend you read this entire [text A-Frame](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/components/text.html#fonts) documentation page or at least the marked paragraph. You can't use standard font file types.

In A-Frame they decided to go with the following formats:

- MSDF
- SDF

Those are "images" of every single letter in a specific font with a .json file describing that image.

Example of MSDF image file (Montserrat-Italic):

[image]

#### Working Example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
        <style>
        
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a-scene>
        <a-text value="hello in your font"
                position="0 1.6 -1"
                color="red"
                negate="false"
                font="https://cdn.glitch.com/b4adbd04-68ad-4b83-8ff1-0cfe5e5c37ec%2Fgeorgia-msdf.json"
                font-image="https://cdn.glitch.com/b4adbd04-68ad-4b83-8ff1-0cfe5e5c37ec%2Fgeorgia.png?v=1619693337804">
          </a-text>
          <a-text value="hello in regular"
                position="0 2 -1"
                color="red">
          </a-text>
        </a-scene>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ah ok, is that the same if I just want the text to appear in A-Frame, but as 2D text?

Comment: if you want to use it inside your 3d scene that's the only way I'm afraid (at least that's what the documentation says). If you need 2d text like a UI or something maybe you can try to overlay a standard HTML text on top of a-frame scene? Then you would have to play wits z-index and positioning. But it won't be a part of a-frame scene

Comment: Ah ok I see, ill do it the document way then, thanks for the help!

Comment: I did as the document said, and generated the MSDF font to put into a mixin, but its not showing up and I cant figure out why... am I not meant to include it as an asset? this is the code: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/vr-climate-change-memorial

Comment: when using MSDF you need to have json and png files in the same location, these are treated like files, not assets. You can just use the `font` parameter in **<**a-text**>** element. Something like this should work `<a-text font="https://cdn.glitch.com/b4adbd04-68ad-4b83-8ff1-0cfe5e5c37ec%2Fgeorgia-msdf.json" value="Hello World"></a-text>` but you need to upload the .png also as it will look for it when loading the json. From the documentation:
> (...) then put both png and json files to your A-Frame directory (...)

Comment: regarding my last comment. It was partialy wrong and I cant edit it anymore. Sooo you dont need to have both files in the same location, you can specify the png and json file locations by using attributes as shown in the example above. But if you specify only json using `font` parameter then it will look for the png file based on what json sais (usualy the same location)